# error de conexión CORS php

Tags: php

buen día me aparece este error en consola cuando intento conectarme a mi php desde mi hosting, aparece un error de cors, he intentado solucionarlo pero sigue apareciendo el error. No se que me falta para poder habilitar los "cors"

error:

```
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.
```

user.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
?>
```

Comment: No puedes consumir desde tu hosting (https://hosting.com) una api o cualquier servicio, los navegadores bloquearán las peticiones hacía tu Localhost ya sea por las CORS o el Protocolo Https, en tu caso, supongo, el bloqueo es por el protocolo Https de tu web y el protocolo http de tu localhost.

Puedes intentar (aunque suponiendo que con poco éxito) habilitar las Cors desde la web. pero lo correcto sería despliegar tu servicio sobre un servidor Https.

Comment: pero solo me pasa con el hosting actual que tengo , con los anteriores hosting no me pasaba esto, que debo habilitar o colocar ?

Comment: Hola. No entiendo qué quieres decir con *cuando intento conectarme a mi php desde mi hosting*, ¿podrías explicar qué es lo que intentas hacer exactamente?

Comment: coloque mi api php a un hosting pero cuando intento conectarme me aparase un error de CORS en consola y no he podido darle acceso, intente varias formas como menciono en la pregunta pero no he podido.

Comment: Pero, ¿tienes un dominio alojado en ese hosting? En ese caso, debes cambiar `localhost` por el nombre del dominio.

Answer (score 0):

Una petición preflight CORS es una petición CORS realizada para comprobar si el protocolo CORS es comprendido.

puedes documentarte [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

Aqui tienes como lo he solucionado

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token, Content-Type');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
    header('Content-Length: 0');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    die();
}

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```